# Excel Formula if | and

Tags: excel, if-statement

I need some help with an Excel formula

```
╔═══════════════╦═════════╗
║   SALE PRICE  ║  Bonus  ║
╠═══════╦═══════╬═════════╣
║   0   ║ 14999 ║  $25.00 ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═════════╣
║ 15000 ║ 20000 ║  $50.00 ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═════════╣
║ 20001 ║ 25000 ║ $125.00 ║
╠═══════╩═══════╬═════════╣
║     25001+    ║ $250.00 ║
╚═══════════════╩═════════╝
```

The above table is the data I need to extract when the sale price is entered into a field.

For example.....

Cell `D24` is the BONUS FIELD
Cell `E29` is the SALE PRICE FIELD

If the sale price is between **$0-$14,999**, then I want cell `D24` to auto-populate **$25.00**. Then, if the sale price is between **$15,000-$20,000** I want Cell `D24` to auto-populate **$50**. Then, if the sale price is between **$20,001-$25,000** I want Cell `D24` to auto-populate **$125**. Then finally, if the sale price is **$25,001+** I want Cell `D24` to auto-populate **$250**.

Comment: enter image description hereThank you for your reply....

I don't think the formula you gave me will work.

I will upload a screenshot of the excel worksheet. I have highighted the fields in red.

When a sale price is entered at Cell E29, I want it to populate the correct bonus according to the table. When the sale price is $nil, I want the bonus to read $nil also.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

try,

```
=25+(A2>15000)*25+(A2>20000)*75+(A2>25000)*125
```

Comment: **To OP:** to add to why this works, the `A2>####` is acting as a Boolean function that will return `1` or `0`, which is then multiplied by 25, 75, and/or 125 and then ultimately the products are summed together. Obviously, any number that is multiplied by a 0 returns a `0`.

Answer (score 0):

this formula seems to work but only the first rule being 0-14999.....how do I add another rule to the existing formula.

=IF(AND(E29>=0,E29<=14999),25,0)